# Given that AIH = 90 degrees, find the circumradius of the triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

This is problem 11 from the 2019 Japan Junior Math Olympiad preliminary round:

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with incenter $I$ and orthocenter $H$. If $\angle AIH = 90^{\circ}$, $AI = 5$, and $AH = 6$, find the circumradius of $ABC.$

I tried angle chasing and using law of sines multiple times, but it did not give any useful results. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: It is generally expected that you attach a suitable diagram along with the post, as well as show us, in writing, what exactly you got with the law of sines and angle chasing.

Comment: Hint: Your question is very good and it is not fair be closed. To prevent this make this effort and include it in your question: You must use Euler's theorem that say $d^2=R(R-2r)$ where $d =IO$ , O is circumcenter  with radius R and r is the radius of inscribed circle centered at I. Try to find d and r.

Answer (score 1):

**First solution:**
Here is a combined geometric-analytic solution, it seemed to be the simplest,
at least as a first solution, since there is an immediate plan to proceed.
I am avoiding trigonometry. An advantage of this approach is the fact, that finally we have a concrete realization on the paper of the given triangle (existence!)
described by the given properties, so we have then immediately the vertices, the sides, etc.

The idea of this plan is as follows.
We try to realize the picture

[image: math stackexchange question 4528422 orthocenter incenter]

by starting from the given points, $A,H,I$, and reconstructing all other points.
In the picture, $D,E,F$ are the feet of the heights on the corresponding opposite sides of the vertices,
and $E'$ is the reflection of $E$ w.r.t. the angle bisector $AIS$ in $A$, where $S\in BC$.

We place the points $A,H,I$ on a cartesian coordinate system, simplest decision would be maybe to use $I=(0,0)$, $A=(5,0)$, and $H=(0, \sqrt{6^2-5^2})=(0,\sqrt {11})$,
and consider the point $E=(x,y)\in AC$,
the foot of the height from $B$, as an unknown quantity.
Of course, this point is a point on the circle $\odot(AIH)$ with diameter $AH$, so we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \left(x-\frac 52\right)^2 +
  \left(y-\frac {\sqrt{11}}2\right)^2 &=
  \left(0-\frac 52\right)^2 +
  \left(0-\frac {\sqrt{11}}2\right)^2 \ ,\qquad\text{ i.e.}
  \\
  x^2-5x + y^2-ay &=0
  \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
For a quick typing, i use above and below
$$a=\sqrt {11}\ .$$
We compute then equations in the capital variables $(X,Y)$ for relevant geometric objects:

- for $AE =AC$, and $CH$ which is perpendicular on $AE'$, thus getting $C$ in the intersection,
- for $AE'=AB$, and $BH=HE$, thus getting $B$ in the intersection,
- for $BC$
  and then $H$ is the orthocenter of $\Delta ABC$, being on two heights, and we check that $I$ is the incenter.

The above data is quickly computed...
$$
\begin{aligned}
  A=(5,0)\ &
  \\
  E=(x,y)\ &
  \\
  AE=AC\ &:\ & 0&=
                  \begin{vmatrix}
                    1&X&Y\\1&x&y\\1&5&0
                  \end{vmatrix} = -5y + Xy + Y(5-x)
  \\
  E'=(x,-y)\ &
  \\
  AE'=AB\ &:\ & 0&=
                   \begin{vmatrix}
                     1&X&Y\\1&x&-y\\1&5&0
                   \end{vmatrix} = +5y - Xy + Y(5-x)
  \\
  H = (0,a)\ &
  \\
  HE=BE\ &:\ & 0&=
                  \begin{vmatrix}
                    1&X&Y\\1&x&y\\1&0&a
                  \end{vmatrix} = xa + X(y-a) - Yx
  \\
  HC\ &:\ &0&= +(Y-a)y + (X-0)(5-x)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We obtain the intersections:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  B &=
      \frac 1{2xy -ax -5y +5a}
      \Big( \ -ax^2 +5xy +5ax\ ,\ axy - 5ay + 5y^2\ \Big)\ ,
  \\
  C &=
      \frac 1{x^2 - y^2 - 10x + 25}
      \Big(\ -axy + 5ay -5y^2\ ,\ -ay^2 - 5xy +25y\ \Big)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And now it is simply said "check that $I$ is the incenter of $\Delta ABC$", well
we can do this with a disproportional amount of computations, but the better idea
is to get more geometric insight, so that possibly there is a simpler check.
We pause the analytic part searching for geometric properties.

---

Let us denote by $y$ (used shortly, not that of the second component of $E$...)
the measure of the angle $\widehat{HAI}$:

[image: math stackexchange question 4528422 orthocenter incenter is circumcenter]

Then the same angle is in two other places, in $E,F$
$$
y
= \widehat{HAI}
= \widehat{HFI}
= \widehat{HEI}
\ ,
$$
because $AEIHF$ is cyclic, as insured by the known given right angles in $E, F, I$.
This implies
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \widehat{ISB} =\widehat{ASD} = 90^\circ-\widehat{DAS} = 90^\circ -y
  &=90^\circ-\widehat{HFI} =\widehat{IFA}\\
  &=90^\circ-\widehat{HEI} =\widehat{IEC}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so both $IFBS$ and $IECS$ are cyclic, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \widehat{ISF} &= \widehat{IBF} = \widehat{SBI} = \widehat{SFI}\ ,\\
  \widehat{ISE} &= \widehat{ICE} = \widehat{SCI} = \widehat{SEI}\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
so the triangles $\Delta ISF$ and $\Delta ISE$ are isosceles in $I$, giving
$$
\color{blue}{\boxed{\qquad IE = IF = IS\qquad }}
$$
and this relation is possibly simpler for an analytic check.

---

Using a computer algebra system, here sage, the values for $x,y$ are now computed as follows
using the variable $r$ with $r^2=x^2+y^2=IE^2$...

```
F.<a> = QuadraticField(11)
R.<x,y, r, XB,YB, XC,YC> = PolynomialRing(F)

J = R.ideal([
    5*y - XB*y + YB*(5-x),
    x*a + XB*(y-a) - YB*x,
    
    -5*y + XC*y + YC*(5-x),
    (YC-a)*y + XC*(5-x),
    
    r^2 - x^2 - y^2,
    x^2 - 5*x + y^2 - a*y, 
    matrix(3, 3, [1, XB, YB, 1, XC, YC, 1, -r, 0]).det(),
])
```

And with the above:

```
for gen in J.elimination_ideal([XB, XC, YB, YC, r, y]).gens():
    print(f"x satisfies the equation:\n{gen.factor()} = 0")

for gen in J.elimination_ideal([XB, XC, YB, YC, r, x]).gens():
    print(f"y satisfies the equation:\n{gen.factor()} = 0")
```

The prints are:

```
x satisfies the equation:
(11250) * (x - 35/18) * (x + (-12/25*a - 9/5)) * (x + (12/25*a - 9/5)) * (x - 5)^2 * x^3 = 0

y satisfies the equation:
(11250) * (y + (-a)) * (y + (-25/18*a)) * (y + (-9/25*a - 12/5)) * (y + (-9/25*a + 12/5)) * y^3 = 0
```

The values for $x$ equal to $0$, $5$, and $35/18$ lead to degenerated cases.
The remained values for $(x,y)$ that correspond to a solution are "almost Galois conjugated" ($x$ is, and the $y$-components has the scaling $a=IH$),
and if $E=E_1=(x_1,y_1)$ is one solution, then the other solution $E_2=(x_2,y_2)$ is exactly the point $F_1$
corresponding to $E_1$. This is because of the fact that if $\Delta ABC$ is a solution, then
$\Delta ACB$ is also a solution. We obatin a unique valid geometric situation up to exchanging $B$ and $C$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  E &= (x,y) =
  \frac 1{25}
  (\ 45+12a\ ,\ -60+9a\ )
  \approx (\ 3.39198\ ,\ -1.20602\ )
  % (\ 3.39197989937059\dots\ ,\ -1.20601507547206\dots\ )
\ ,
  \\
  F &= (x,y) =
  \frac 1{25}
  \left(\ 45-12a\ ,\ +60+9a\ \right)
  \approx (\ 0.20802\ ,\ 3.594\ )
  % (\ 0.208020100629408\dots\ ,\ 3.59398492452794\dots\ )
  \ .
  \\
&\qquad\text{Then:}
  \\
  B &= \frac 17(\ -45+12a\ ,\ +60-9a\ )
  \approx(\ -0.74293\ ,\ 4.3072\dots\ )
  % (\ -0.742928930819315\dots\ ,\ 4.30719669811449\dots\ )
 \ ,
  \\
  C &= \frac 17(\ -45-12a\ ,\ -60-9a\ )
  \approx(\ -12.11421\ ,\ -12.83566\ )
  % (\ -12.1142139263235\dots\ ,\ -12.8356604447427\dots\ )
  \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
Here is the picture for the solution.

[image: math stackexchange question 4528422 realization]

We can now compute everything for this triangle. A possibility to get the circumradius $R$ is to compute the
sides $a,b,c$ of $\Delta AC$, then the area $S$, and finally use $4R = abc/S$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
  a^2 &= BC^2 = \frac 1{7^2}(\ ((-45+12a) - (-45-12a))^2 + ((60-9a) - (-60-9a))^2\ )
  \\
  &= \frac 1{7^2}(11\cdot 24^2 + 120^2)
  = \frac 1{7^2}(11\cdot 24^2 + 120^2) =\frac {144^2}{7^2}\ ,
  \\
  b^2 &= CA^2 = \frac 1{7^2}(\ ((-45-12a) -7\cdot 5)^2 + (-60-9a)^2\ ) = \frac 1{7^2}(100+15a)^2\ ,
  \\
  c^2 &= AB^2 = \frac 1{7^2}(\ (7\cdot 5 - (-45+12a))^2 + (60-9a)^2\ ) = \frac 1{7^2}(100-15a)^2\ ,
  \\[2mm]
  a &= 144/7\ ,\\
  b &= (100+15a)/7\ ,\\
  c &= (100-15a)/7\ ,\\
  p &:=\frac 12(a+b+c) = 344/14=172/7\ ,\\
  S^2 &=p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c) =\frac 1{7^4}\cdot 172\cdot 28\cdot (72-15a)(72+15a)
  \\&=\frac 1{7^4}\cdot 2^2\cdot 43\cdot 2^2\cdot 7\cdot 3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 43\ ,
  \\
  S &= \frac 17\cdot 2^2\cdot 3\cdot 43\ ,
  \\
  \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{ =\frac{abc}{4S} =\boxed{\frac{75}{7}}\approx 10.\;714285\;714285\dots}\ ,
  \\
  r &=\frac Sp =3\ ,
  \\
  \operatorname{distance}(O, BC)^2 &=R^2 -(a/2)^2=\frac 1{7^2}(75^2-72^2)=\frac 1{7^2}(75-72)(75+72)=\frac 1{7^2}3\cdot 3\cdot 7^2\ ,
  \\
  \operatorname{distance}(O, BC) &=3 =r\ .  
\end{aligned}
$$

---

---

**Second solution:**
At this point the problem is solved, but there is too much of a coincidence in the last relation,
the one showing that the distance from $O$, and from $I$ to the side $BC$ is the same one, $r=3$,
so that we would want to understand in general what happens. Now it is also transparent how such problems are "composed".
Certainly, there was a known property behind, then
the problem was stated by hiding this property,
and taking some particular case. So we just forget the stucture,
in order to get a competition problem with less hints.
This may be a reasonable strategy, in order to separate the candidates, their aptitudes,
but one should not forget the ones that have invested some work, did not find the missing bridge, just because of missed luck,
and may see inside the mathematical world only a world of puzzles, thus getting them at distance, maybe forever.

Which property can be extracted?

**Proposition ONE:**
Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle, denote by $O,I,H$ as usual its circumcenter, incenter, and orthocenter.
Then
$OI\|BC$ is equivalent to $\widehat{AIH} = 90^\circ$.

**Proof:** Recall the above blue identity, $IE=IF=IS$, and construct $S'\in BC$ so that $IS=IS'$, and $\Delta ISS'$ isosceles.
(So $S,S'$ are reflected w.r.t. the perpendicular line from $I$ on $BC$.)

Then $\Delta CEI=\Delta CS'I$, and $\Delta BFI=\Delta BS'I$, giving:
$$
a = BC = BS'+S'C = BF+CE =a(\cos B+\cos C)\ ,
$$
so we obtain the relation
$$1=\cos B+\cos C\ ,$$
or after writing $\cos B=(a^2+c^2-b^2)/(\dots)$ and the similar relation for $\cos C$:
$$
2abc = (a^2 - b^2 - c^2 +2bc)(b+c) \ .
$$
Let us try to get an equivalent analytic restatement for the parallelity $OI\|BC$. The distance from
$O$ to $BC$ is in $\Delta OBC$ seen to be $R\cos A$. Then we restate equivalently:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \frac Sp = r &= R\cos A\ ,\\
  16 S^2 &= 16 RS \; p\cos A = 4abc \;p\cos A\ ,\\
  16 S^2 &= a(a+b+c)(b^2 + c^2 - a^2)\ ,\\
  (a+b+c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c) &= a(a+b+c)(b^2 + c^2 - a^2)\ ,\\
  (b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c) &= a(b^2 + c^2 - a^2)\ ,\\
  (b+c-a)(a^2 - (b-c)^2) &= a(b^2+c^2-a^2)\ ,\\
  (b+c)(a^2 - (b-c)^2) &= a((a^2 - (b-c)^2) + (b^2+c^2-a^2))\ ,\\
  (b+c)(a^2 - (b-c)^2) &= 2abc\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which is the same relation.

$\square$

---

Now we get closer, and can formulate:

**Proposition TWO:**
Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle with notations as in Proposition ONE, so that
$OI\|BC$ and/or $\widehat{AIH} = 90^\circ$. Consider its Euler circle $(9)$ centered in $9$, the mid point of $OH$.
Let $A_1,A_2$ be the mid points of the segments $BC$, and respectively $AH$. Then
$$OA_1 =AA_2=A_2H=r\ .$$

*Bonus:* The points $A_1,A_2,I,9$ are colinear.

[image: math stackexchange question 4528422 position of the euler circle nine points center]

**Proof** of Proposition TWO:

Since $D$ (foot of the height from $A$), and $A_1,A_2$ are on the Euler circle, and $\Delta A_1D A_2$ has a right angle in $D$,
the segment $A_1A_2$ is a diameter in the Euler circle, and thus $9$ is the mid point of $A_1A_2$, in particular on $A_1A_2$.
Also, $9$ is on the side bisector of $DA_1$, and on $OH$, thus the mid point of $OH$. So $\Delta 9A_1O=\Delta 9A_2 H$, giving
$$ r = OA_1=A_2H=AA_2\ .$$

$\square$

We do not need the bonus point for the stated question, but it is a nice property, so let us give the argument.
(Please skip if this feels like off-topic.)

**Proof of the Bonus:

Let $A'$ be the mid point of the arc $\overset\frown{BC}$, so that $AA'$ is the angle bisector in $A$ in $\Delta ABC$,
and $OA'$ is the side bisector of $BC$.
We show $A_1I=A_1A'$, so let us comupte
$$
\begin{aligned}
  A_1I^2 - A_1A'{}^2
  &= A_1O^2 + OI^2 - (OA'-OA_1)^2\\
  &=r^2 + R(R-2r) -(R-r)^2\\
  &=0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So indeed, $\Delta A_1IA'$ is isosceles, let us compare it with $\Delta A_2IA$,
they are similar (isosceles, and same angles in $A,A'$), so their angles in $I$ coincide,
and using $A,I,A'$ colinear we obtain $A_2,I,A_1$ colinear.

$\square$

---

Now we can finish the second solution in a simple manner.
In the given situation, the distance from $I$ to the sides of $\Delta ABC$
is the same as the one from $O$ to $BC$, which is
$$
OA_1 = HA_2 = A_2A=\frac 12HA=\frac 62=3\ .
$$
So the point $E$ is located on the circle $(AIH)$ centered in $A_2$, so that the distance from $I$
to $AE$ is $3$. Consider the projection of $I$ on $AE$, it builds a triangle with sides $AI=5$, $3$,
and $\sqrt {5^2-3^2}=4$, so the slope of $AE$ is $3/4$ in a coordinate system with origin in $I$, and $A=(5,0)$.
Then $AE$ intersects the $y$-axis in the point with coordinates $(0,-15/4)$, the equation of $AE$ is
$$
AE\ :\ 3(X-5) = 4Y\ ,
$$
and we search $E=(x,y)$ ($E\ne A$) on this line, and on the circle
$$
\odot(AIH)\ :\  X^2-5X + Y^2-aY =0\ ,\qquad a=\sqrt {11}\ ,
$$
This gives $E$, and similarly we obtain $F$, using the intersection of the circle with the reflected line
through $A$ and $(0, 15/4)$.
The two solutions are determining the points $E,F$, they are
$$
\frac 1{25}(\ 45\pm 12a\ ,\ \mp 60+9a\ )\ .
$$
Now we can proceed as in the first solution, determine one by one the points $B,C,A_1,O$, or we can
use the Euler circle, which is
$$
\odot(EA_2F)\ :\
\left(x+\frac{55}{28}\right)^2 +
\left(y+\frac{11a}{28}\right)^2
=
\left(\frac{75}{14}\right)^2 \ .
$$
Its radius is half $R$, so
$$
\color{red}{\boxed{\qquad
R=\frac{75}7\ .\qquad}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint: You have to show following facts shown in the figure:

1-With conditions stated in question $r=6$.

2- $d=AB\approx 7.1$ where d is distance between I and O the centers of inscribed and circumcircles.

then use formula $d^2=R(R-2r)$ to find value $R\approx 10.7$